# How to display icons conditionally using v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a data set on which i am iterating to display certain fields in a `v-data-table`. How can i make it so that if the icon field has a value of `G`, a certain icon would appear. If it has `F`, a different icon would appear and if it has `GF` then two icons would appears in the same row.

Here is a sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/KKwRgzW).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Icon Field',
          value: 'icon'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          icon: 'GF'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          icon: 'F'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          icon: 'G'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          icon: 'GF'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
         <td> {{ props.item.icon}} </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I tried setting a `v-if =  props.item.icon == 'GF'` but that didn't seem to work. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to add list of icons you want to render and then use the `v-for`

[link to working solution](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/zYxjKmy?editors=1010)

```js
// data

icons: {
  F: ["gavel"],
  G: ["event"],
  GF: ["gavel", "event"]
},
```

```js
// template


<td>
  <v-icon v-for="icon in icons[props.item.icon]">{{icon}}</v-icon>
</td>
```

This way you have nice scalable solution :-)

Comment: What if i wanna assign each icon it's own unique color? Would i create another color array?

Comment: @Somethingwhatever No. Change Strings into Objects in the Arrays. Look: `F: [{ name: "gravel", color: "purple" }]` and in a template use `{{ icon.name }}`.

Comment: gotcha, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You mustn't use v-if inside v-for. You could filter the array and then iterate.

There is a useful link to Vue best practices
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential

Answer (score 0):

Use Vue filters, for further information read from here
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

```js
...
filters: {
  getIcon(value) {
    if (value == "G") {
      return "your icon"
    }
    else if (value == "GF") {
      return "your icon"
    }
    else if (value == "F") {
      return "your icon"
    }
  }
}
...
```

```html
...
<td> {{ props.item.icon | getIcon}} </td>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in Vue but something like this should work, you can use an array for icons & use "icons.map(icon => <>)"etc.

let desserts = [

```
{
    name: 'ice',
    icon: 'G'
},
{
    name: 'ice2',
    icon: 'E'
},
{
    name: 'ice3',
    icon: 'F'
}
```

]

let icons = {

```
val1: '',
val2: '',
val3: ''
```

};

desserts.forEach((dessert) => {

```
switch(dessert.icon){
    case 'G':
        icons.val1 = 'http://iconurl'
    case 'E':
        icons.val2 = 'http://iconurl'
    case 'F':
        icons.val3 = 'http://iconurl'
}
```

})